# Is it easy to save changes as draft on a published page?

Tags: 8

I'm editing a published page using Drupal and would like to save my changes as draft before publishing an updated version. This must be possible, but how?

Comment: I don't really get your question. Please specify how we can help you and provide some more details as which Drupal version you are using and on which point of your own research you got stuck.

Comment: Out of the box, no, that's not possible. You would need to set up a workflow to match your requirements. It's not possible to help you without more information about your environment, requirements, what you've already tried to set up, etc

Answer (score 2):

> Is it easy to save changes as draft on a published page?

**No!** The proof of that is what the [Workflow Initiative](https://www.drupal.org/node/2721129) is all about (it takes an *initiative* to get it done). Here is a quote from it:

> The 'Draft' workflow state is a long-requested usability improvement, but may seem like a small change. What is more exciting is that the list of workflow states is fully configurable

Refer to [Moving the Drupal 8 workflow initiative along](https://dri.es/moving-the-drupal-8-workflow-initiative-along), from *famous* Dries, for a very good article (and interesting animations) about it.

Comment: *lol* This answer made my eve.